# Accented Character Conversion DB to Java

Tags: java, csv, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

We have a accented Character value in DB2 table as **"POKORNÝ"** when i am trying to process the data through java and writing into csv file the value has been changed to **"POKORNÃ"**. I tried converting the value to UTF-8 before writing into CSV but no luck.

DB :
[image]

CSV :

[image]

Comment: What platform? How are you opening/creating the the CSV file? You might find this helpful (if Windows): https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding#1-default-charset

Comment: Windows in local but Prod Platform will be Unix. Am using FileWriter and PrintWriter for opening/creating csv.

Comment: The link I provided explains your problem and includes several fixes. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for ur time. let me try :)